# HTML 5 drop down menu

Tags: css

Sorry I'm back again with another question.  I'm trying to convert my html page into html5 by removing some of the `<div>` tags with `<section>`, `<header>`, etc.  The drop down menu isn't working anymore - big gaps are appearing between the drop down bars.  Would someone mind having a look? Thanks in advance.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Home Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<div id= "container">
<header>
    <img src="images/title.jpg"/>
</header>

<nav>
<ul class="navbar">
<li>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">HTML5</a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Tutorial 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Tutorial 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Tutorial 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">CSS3</a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Tutorial 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Tutorial 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Tutorial 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">Links</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>

<section>
<h2>Home Page</h2>
<p>This is a test paragraph. .</p>
</section>

<footer>
    <ul class="lowernav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">HTML5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CSS3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p id="copyright">Copyright blach blach blach!</p>
</footer>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and the CSS is:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
#container{
    width:800px;
    background-color:#00FF00;
    border:1px solid black;
    height:1000px;
    z-index:-9;
    margin:auto;
}

#logo{

    background-color:#FF0033;
    border:#000 1px;
    width:800px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;

}

nav {

    background-color:#FFF;
    border:#000 1px;
    width:800px;
    height:30px;

}

section{

    background-color:#6F3;
    border:#000 1px;
    width:780px;
    height:400px;
    margin:10px;
}

footer{

    background-color:#FF0;
    border:#000 1px;
    width:800px;
    height:100px;
}

.navbar {
/*border-right: 1px solid #54879D;*/
  height: 40px;
margin:    0 0 0 0;
padding: 0;

}

.navbar li {
background-color: #366B82;
float: left;
font: bold 12px/1.2em Arial,Verdana,Helvetica;
height: auto;
list-style: none outside none;
margin: 20 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
width: 160px;
}

.navbar a {
/*  border-left: 1px solid #54879D;*/
border-right: 1px solid #1F5065;
color: #FFFFFF;
display: block;
padding: 10px 10px;
text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar li:hover, a:hover {
background-color: #54879D;
}

.navbar li ul {
display: none;
height: auto;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position:absolute;
}

.navbar li:hover ul {
display: block;
}

.navbar li ul li {
background-color: #54879D;
float:none;
}

.navbar li ul li a {
border-color: #74A3B7 #1F5065 #1F5065;
border-left: 1px solid #1F5065;
border-right: 1px solid #1F5065;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;

}
.navbar li ul li a:hover {
background-color: #366B82;
}

.lowernav{
height: 20px;
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 0;
width: 350px;
margin: auto;
}

.lowernav li {
float: left;
list-style: none;
margin: 0 0;
padding: 0;
width:20%;

}

.lowernav a {
border-right:1px solid #ffffff;
padding: 0 10px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: center;

}

.lowernav a:hover {
color: red;
background-color:transparent;


}

#copyright{
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should add `display:block` for these new html5 elements (not all browsers understand them).

Comment: Looks fine in FF24 - http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/WJzWD/

Answer (score 1):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EEfPH/)**

**css**

```
@charset "utf-8";
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#container {
    width: 800px;
    background-color: #00FF00;
    border: 1px solid black;
    z-index: -9;
    margin: auto;
}
#logo {
    background-color: #FF0033;
    border: #000 1px;
    width: 800px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
nav {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: #000 1px;
    width: 800px;
    height: 30px;
}
section {
    background-color: #6F3;
    border: #000 1px;
    width: 780px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 10px;
}
footer {
    background-color: #FF0;
    border: #000 1px;
    width: 800px;
    height: 100px;
}
.navbar {
    /*border-right: 1px solid #54879D;*/
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.navbar ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.navbar li {
    background-color: #366B82;
    float: left;
    font: bold 12px/1.2em Arial, Verdana, Helvetica;
    height: auto;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 20 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 160px;
}
.navbar a {
    /*  border-left: 1px solid #54879D;*/
    border-right: 1px solid #1F5065;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar li:hover, a:hover {
    background-color: #54879D;
}
.navbar li ul {
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.navbar li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
.navbar li ul li {
    background-color: #54879D;
    float: none;
}
.navbar li ul li a {
    border-color: #74A3B7 #1F5065 #1F5065;
    border-left: 1px solid #1F5065;
    border-right: 1px solid #1F5065;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}
.navbar li ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #366B82;
}
.lowernav {
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0;
    width: 350px;
    margin: auto;
}
.lowernav li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 20%;
}
.lowernav a {
    border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
.lowernav a:hover {
    color: red;
    background-color: transparent;
}
#copyright {
    text-align: center;
}
footer p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}/* CSS Document */
```

Comment: thanks for taking a look but I'm still getting the problem in Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line

```
margin: 20 0;
```

from

```
.navbar li
```